# R: equally space points in an interval but not include the endpoints

Tags: r

Suppose I want to generate equally spaced points within an interval in R, I found the `seq` function will do this, but the results shows as:

```
seq(0, 1, length.out = 10)
[1] 0.0000000 0.1111111 0.2222222 0.3333333 0.4444444 0.5555556 0.6666667
[8] 0.7777778 0.8888889 1.0000000
```

If we want to generate `0.1, 0.2,...,0.9, 1.0`, how could I include one end point and not the other one?

Thanks!

Comment: @markus In this case, I will have to find the distance between two points every time, I need to do this for different intervals, so I was trying to see whether there is an easier way to do so.

Comment: Left this as a comment because I somehow thought this is not what you are looking for. How about: `n <- 10; left <- 0; right <- 1; step <- right / n; seq(left + step, right, length.out = n)` ? This could easily be written as a function.

Comment: @markus Well put, very similar to my approach below

Comment: @markus Yes, thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for. And to be honest, this is quite a similar way that I am using right now. But I was wondering if there is other functions could do this just by specifying a value of some parameters?

Comment: Have a look at `?pretty` - this may also help. For example, `pretty(1:10, n = 10) / 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option similar to @duckmayr's answer with an additional `aligned` argument

```
fun <- function(minimum, maximum, length_out, aligned = c("left", "right")) {
  type <- match.arg(aligned)
  step <- maximum / length_out

  if(type == "left") {
    seq(minimum, right - step, length.out = length_out)
  } else {
    seq(minimum + step, right, length.out = length_out)
  }
}

fun(0, 1, 10) # default is "left"
# [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9

fun(0, 1, 10, "right")
# [1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

fun(0, 1, 10, "abc")
```

> error in match.arg(aligned) : 'arg' should be one of “left”, “right”

Answer (score 1):

You could do that programatically with something like this:

```
f <- function(from, to, length.out) {
    length.out <- length.out + 1
    result <- seq(from, to, length.out = length.out)
    result <- result[-1]
    return(result)
}

f(0, 1, 10)
# [1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

The idea is that we'll make a sequence with length one more than what you actually want; this will space the elements how you want them, then we just discard the unwanted initial element.